# Is there any way to handle Server SSL certificate upgrade?

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, httpclient

Here is a situation,

1. Our application is consuming a REST service over HTTPS.
2. To take care of SSL, We have exported the public certificate from the browser (By Accessing the URL, the Public Certificate gets installed).
3. We imported that certificate in our local client side JKS store.
4. What client (The party hosting the REST web services) is saying that they keep on upgrading certificates every year (as the certificate validity is one year).
5. They have sent a certificate chain (Root cert and one intermediate authority and NO certificate), and asked us to import it in our keystore, so that whenever they upgrade, our client will always work.
6. I suspected that it wont work. We could import the certificate chain in truststore but when we invoke REST, we get error as bellow,

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: **End user tried to act as a CA**
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1884)

6. I believe that everytime they upgrade the certificate, the same also needs to be imported in our keystore for it to work.

Question is, is this the only way forward(Update your truststore everytime the server public cert is upgraded), or there is a way out ?

Comment: 6. You are wrong. It will work. You've done it wrong. You need to import it into your *truststore*, not your keystore. If the certificate is signed by a recognized CA, you don't even need to do that.

Comment: We use truststore. It was typo.Corrected it. We have trust store and no keystore. There is no client auth. We could import and cert and facing the error mentioned.